# Optimizing a Django query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 models like these:

```
class Client(models.Model):
  // some fields

class Transaction(models.Model):
  client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  amount = DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
```

I want to write a query that add the last created `Transaction` amount, per clients, only if `created` is lower than a provided `date` argument.

For example, if I have a dataset like this one, and that the provided `date` is 01/20:

```
Client1:
- Transaction 1, created on 01/15, 5€
- Transaction 2, created on 01/16, 6€
- Transaction 3, created on 01/22, 7€

Client2:
- Transaction 4, created on 01/18, 8€
- Transaction 5, created on 01/19, 9€
- Transaction 6, created on 01/21, 10€

Client3:
- Transaction 7, created on 01/21, 11€
```

Then, the query should return `15` (6€ + 9€ from transaction 2 and 5).

From a performance view, my purpose is to avoid having N queries for N clients.

Currently, I have trouble selecting the right `Transaction` objects.
Maybe I could start by:
`Transaction.objects.filter(created__lt=date).select_related('client')`.
But then, I can't figure out how to select only the latest *per client*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want the latest transaction for each client, given that the transaction occurred before the given date?

Comment: an idea ...
- filter(created__lt=date)
- group by client
- max(created)

But it does not return the amount, only the date.

Maybe you should write a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: @wholevinski Asbolutely. Then I would sum all of these transaction amounts.

Comment: How big is the dataset? Have you looked at using pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Django's docs on [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/), the usage of [Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#sum), [SubQuery expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions), and [QuerySet.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values). With those we can construct a single query through the ORM to get at what you're after, allowing the database to do all the work:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Subquery, OuterRef
from django.utils import timezone

from . import models


# first, start with the client list, rather than the transaction list    
aggregation = models.Client.objects.aggregate(
    # aggregate the sum of our per client sub queries
    result=Sum(
        Subquery(
            models.Transaction.objects.filter(
                # filter transactions by outer query's client pk
                client=OuterRef('pk'),
                created__lt=timezone.datetime(2018, 1, 20),
            )
            # order descending so the transaction we're after is first in the list
            .order_by('-created')
            # use QuerySet.values() to grab just amount and slice the queryset
            # to limit the subquery result to a single transaction for each client
            .values('amount')[:1]
        )
    )
)
# aggregation == {'result': Decimal('15.00')}
```

Comment: Awesome! `Subquery` is exactly what I was looking for but didn't know it existed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following should do the trick which uses Django's [latest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#latest) QuerySet method

```
total = 0
for client in clients
    try:    
        total += Transactions.filter(client = client).filter(created__lt = date).latest('created').amount
    except DoesNotExist:
         pass
```

Comment: I did something very similar first, but the problem is that it creates one query for every client in the database. Even if you `prefetct_related` the transactions related to the clients, there is still one new query in every round, because of the `filter()` method call.

Comment: would you prefer then to do the filtering in python instead of through database queries? if not, do you know a way your objective can be accomplished through SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, what do you think about both solutions?

Comment: The Django Docs have a whole page on database optimization, which I suggest you read. One header on the page is 'Do database work in the database rather than in Python' and goes on to note filtering is best done in the DB, which seems like a clear answer. You can also use `QuerySet.explain()` as referenced in the doc, but unless you are noticing performance issues with the above solution I say just stick with it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/#database-access-optimization

Comment: I already read it. Actually I noticed huge performances issues since I have many clients, and I will have more. So having 1 query per client is not acceptable. I'm pretty confident that there is a way to process one or two DB queries for all clients for what I want to do. I'm just still looking for how :)

Comment: How far back in time are you looking to go? It says you want to get it before a date, is there also a floor?

Comment: @DavidD. you should try to use `Client` [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to get its `Transaction` in single query: `sum(c.transactions.filter(...).latest(...).amount for c in Client.objects.prefetch_related('transactions'))`